# 'UIView?' does not have a member named 'viewWithTag'

Tags: swift, xcode6

Had this line in my project before and it worked just great:

```
superview.viewWithTag(kGridViewTag).hidden = !superview.viewWithTag(kGridViewTag).hidden
```

XCode-beta5 shows me an error:

```
'UIView?' does not have a member named 'viewWithTag'
```

How I fixed it:

```
superview!.viewWithTag(kGridViewTag)!.hidden = !superview!.viewWithTag(kGridViewTag)!.hidden
```

But it looks too ugly to be the Swift-way.

What is the right way to fix this?

Comment: an _optional_ cannot be at the left side of the operand in _Swift_, currently. you need to unwarp it first.

Comment: @holex, it worked before :( so what, now I need to write these "!!!!!" all over my code?

Comment: the _Swift_ language is a concept language only currently, the language syntax is still flexible and it changes periodically.

Comment: @holex I wouldn't call it a concept language. Sure, it's still in development, and the rest of your comment is 100% correct, but not *concept*. Apple are betting very heavily on Swift - it was conceptual about 4 years ago when they started development on it.

Comment: @holex: I think that changed with beta 5, see "Refinements to Optional Types in Swift" in the release notes.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, I have seen.

Comment: @Jasarien, the _Swift_ currently has essential problems, the Apple has done very bad job if 4 years were not enough to them to finalise the basic _keywords_ and _operators_ for the language... :( they are changed in every 2 weeks when a new beta comes out.

Comment: @holex That's why it's called a developer beta. A lot of changes have come about from developers filing radars asking for improvements. If you are uncomfortable working in such a fluid environment, then I suggest that you wait until Swift is released in a more stable version when Xcode6 comes out of beta.

Comment: @Anorak, maybe we have different definitions about _beta_ and _concept_. :) those essential things should have been clarified in _alpha_ stage already – I have never seen any other new language which has such amount of problem fundamentally, not even _after_ the 1st beta... but I would be happy if you are right about _Swift_, but based on last two months' happening, that language won't be ready in a year time or so. :(

Comment: @holex you're assuming that the syntax is all there is to the language. What about the toolchain, compiler and other intricacies of designing a programming language before you even start to consider syntax and grammar. When you consider Objective-C is 31 years old and is still getting syntax additions and changes, I think 4 years is pretty good going for what Swift is right now.

Comment: What @Jasarien said. Also, a lot of the ugliness the OP is complaining about comes from Cocoa being written in Objective-C and the wrapping and unwrapping is a consequence of handling the possibility of nil returns. That will get better as more of Cocoa starts supporting Swift natively. Which is a good few year away.

Comment: @Jasarien, I guess the technology changed a lot in the last 31 years in IT, and the changes of this technology are much less in the last 4 years. I'm always happy to see keen people – I'm realistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`superview` is an optional (because a view might have no superview), and 
`viewWithTag()` also returns an optional (because a subview with the given tag
might not exist). In beta 4, both methods returned an implicitly unwrapped optional
`UIView!`. In beta 5, the return type changed to an ordinary optional `UIView?`.

A concise way to check for both situations would be to combine "optional chaining"
with an "optional assignment":

```
if let theView = superview?.viewWithTag(kGridViewTag) {
    theView.hidden = !theView.hidden
    // Alternatively: theView.hidden ^= true
}
```

which compiles with both beta 4 and beta 5.

Comment: Why I am not using if-let binding 'cause I know that views/superviews do exist 100%, but I don't like this "!!!!" unwrappings.

Comment: @AndrewShmig: I see what you mean, but I don't know an alternative to the unwrapping. (You could write it as `superview!.viewWithTag(kGridViewTag)!.hidden ^= true` to reduce the number of exclamation marks :)

Comment: @AndrewShmig Yeah; I think that's a deliberate choice of the language design—you're actually *meant* get get a slightly bad feeling when using ! to unwrap, because it can be dangerous. Just a shame it needs doing so much with Cocoa/UIKit interactions at the moment.